# Amazon transcoded video getting slow when loading it first time

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, video

We are working on video site, for that we are adding video in s3 bucket and transcoding that video,  it is working fine for us, but the issue is when i run that transcoded video first time it is getting slowed,  if i will run it second time then it is working fine for us,  so what can be the issue for that? I tried searching lot on google but didn't get any proper help. I need solution for this. Can anyone please tell me how can i resolve this issue ?

Answer (score 0):

For your application AWS cloud front will be an important parameter. configure cloud front with the S3 bucket as source and try calling these videos using cloud front URL and see the difference.
cloud front is a content delivery network and well known for delivering static content.
And as your video runs slow when requested first time and runs smooth when requested 2nd or 3rd time this may be because of browser cache at user machine.
This is a normal behaviour for any static contents on web application or websites.

Thanks